# hidesBottomBarWhenPushed for a custom view

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I want to build a custom tab bar for mya app and I have a tiny problem: The built-in tabBar supports `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`. Is there a way to tell my app that my `CustomTabBar` is a bottom bar? **This is what I want to do *(same UINavController)*:**

```
                              +---------+        +---------+
                              |---------|        |---------| 
                              |         |        |         |
                              |  [btn]  |  --->  |   2nd   |
                              |         |   |    |  view   |
                              |---------|   |    |         |
          there's tabbar -->  | 1  |  2 |   |    |         |  <- no tabbar
                              +---------+   |    +---------+
                                            |
                              pushViewController:animated:
```

My `CustomTabBarController`'s hierarchy is much like the original `UITabBarController`'s:

```
CustomTabBarController
  |- UINavigationController (root: FirstViewController) <- there's a button
  |- UINavigationController (root: SecondViewController)
```

Is there a way to acheive that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your custom tab bar controller inherit from UITabBar UIView? In other words, do you implement the logic for switching views etc. yourself using the content view controller API or do you hijack the UITTabBar?

Comment: Nope, I have to handle all the switching stuff myself. If it inherited from UITabBar, there would be no problem... By the way, can I make my custom UITabBar 44px tall? If yes, it will be a solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4987542/263503, I implemented the following in my custom tab bar controller class:

**CustomTabBarController.h**

```
@interface CustomTabBarController : UITabBarController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

**CustomTabBarController.m**

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
  willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed) {
        self.tabBarImage.hidden = YES;
    } else if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[CustomViewController class]]) {
        self.tabBarImage.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

In addition i needed to know when to show the custom image of the tab bar again. So I check for the class of the viewcontroller added to tabBar.viewcontrollers

Hope this helps.